# Upward Löwenheim Skolem

Tags: logic, model-theory

I'm trying to understand the proof of (a version) of the upward Löwenheim Skolem Theorem, which states that given a language $\mathscr{L}$ and a set of $\mathscr{L}$-sentences $\Sigma$ with a countably infinite model $\mathscr{A}$, there also exists an uncountable model of $\Sigma$.

I understand that first one has to enrich the language with uncountably many new constant-symbols $\{c_i|i\in \mathbb{R}\}$ to get a language $\mathscr{L^*}$, and then considers $\Sigma'=\Sigma \cup\{c_i\neq c_j|i\neq j\}$ and shows that it has an uncountable $\mathscr{L}^*$-model by adding new elements $\{a_i|i\in I\}$ to $\mathscr{A}$, proving that this is a $\mathscr{L}^*$model of every finite subset of $\Sigma'$, and hence due to the compactness theorem also a $\mathscr{L}^*$model of $\Sigma'$.
Then the restriction of $\Sigma'$ is an $\mathscr{L}$-model of $\Sigma$ with the same cardinality as $\mathscr{A}\cup\{a_i|i\in I\}$, i.e. uncountable.

But I am missing the point where I need that there has to exist a countably infinite model in the first place. Why can't it just be finite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reproduction of the proof is a bit off, which is why you're confused.

You're *not* supposed to add new *elements* to the model in the step where you consider the finite subsets of $\Sigma'$. The point here is that the *original* $\mathscr A$ can be a model of every finite subset of $\Sigma'$, *without* adding new individuals, because it has enough elements already to assign meanings to the $c_i$ constants such that sufficiently many of them are different. But this step only works because $\mathscr A$ is infinite; if it were finite there might not be space to make sufficiently many of the $c_i$s map to different different elements.

*After* you have done this, you know that $\Sigma'$ is consistent (by compactness), and the completeness theorem now gives you a *new* model for the entire $\Sigma'$. In this new model *all* the $c_i$s are different, so it must have at least the same cardinality as $I$.

(And then you may need to use the *downwards* Löwenheim-Skolem theorem to cut your new model down to size exactly $|I|$).

---

And now you should also be able to see why the hypothesis can be weakened from "$\Sigma$ has an infinite model" to "for every finite $n$, $\Sigma$ has a model of cardinality at least $n$".

Comment: As a secondary issue: Can one map different constant-symbols to the same individual? And regarding your main point: So I need at least as many different individuals in $\mathscr{A}$ as there are different $c_i$'s appearing in each finite subset of $\Sigma'$ for $\mathscr{A}$ to be a model of said subset?

Comment: @see: (1) There is nothing in the definition of "structure" that prevents two different constant letters from having the same interpretation. This possibility is _necessary_ for the completeness theorem to hold. For example, the theory $\{\forall x\forall y(x=y)\}$ in the language $\{c_1,c_2\}$ is consistent (having more constants that are not mentioned in any axiom doesn't make it easier to derive a contradiction, because a variable can do anything that such a constant does in a proof), but it can only have a model if $c_1$ and $c_2$ are allowed to be interpreted as the same element.

Comment: @see: (2) Yes, that is a good way to think of it. It is not _strictly_ true, in that for _some_ finite subsets of $\Sigma'$ you can get away with fewer elements than that. For example if  you consider the subset $$\{c_1\ne c_2, c_3\ne c_4, \ldots, c_{2n-1}\ne c_{2n} \}$$ then having two elements is enough.

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

Consider the sentence $\forall x \forall y.x = y$. The only models of this sentence have exactly one element, so the upward Löwenheim-Skolem theorem must fail for the set comprising just this sentence. The proof breaks down because $c_1 \neq c_2$ is not satisfiable in any model of this sentence.